# Trouble integrating PayPal standard payment gate on my hostinger VPS website

Tags: php, node.js, json, paypal, vps

I have been working to set up a payment gateway on my VPS website. When I run `npm start` in the terminal locally on my machine and go to `localhost:8888` port, the PayPal gateway works properly in the sandbox environment, but when I actually click on the PayPal button on my site in order to open the same popup, I get:

> "Could not initiate PayPal Checkout...
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "

I have .env, server.js, app.js, checkout.html and package.json, all set up, but cannot seem to find the error as to why the PayPal pop up won't load. It always shows up for a split second, even showing the PayPal logo meaning it is clearly trying to connect, but then disappears. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am not sure what to try or where to begin to solve this issue as this is my first time building on a VPS.

Comment: _"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"_ often means that something the browser expected to be valid JavaScript, was HTML code instead - for example, because an error document response was sent. Go inspect the requests that are happening in your browser dev tools, and check what the response body contains. You might find a human-readable error message as part of an HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

localhost:8888 is the backend portion of PayPal's node.js sample app, if run locally of course.

You need to either deploy the node app on your server, or (more likely if the rest of your site is in PHP) re-implement the entire backend portion of the sample in PHP instead, and deploy that to your site.

When the `fetch` routes in the frontend JS post to your site, they must receive back a valid JSON-formatted response with the expected data. It must be only a JSON string, no additional HTML or text.  The error about "<" is because your site is responding with HTML (likely some 404 error page) and so the frontend cannot proceed because the backend is not giving it a PayPal Order ID to initiate the checkout with.